# setting values to define type in drools in then part of rule

Tags: java, drools, rules

I have a define type in drools like this

```
package referee.security.category;
declare AskedQuestions
question : String
answer : Boolean
end
```

and a Java class for the same type in my java files. It is not sent to drools as I don't know where should I give a reference for this.

```
    @Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class AskedQuestions{
    private String question;
    private boolean answer;
}
```

I have a number of rules and I am trying to set the values to `question` and `answer` variables from the defined type by following this method.

```
rule "Threat: Public Readable -- QRF_1.4 [not true]"
agenda-group "evaluate attack category"
dialect "mvel"
when
     $q1: QRiskFactor(this == QRiskFactor.QRF1_S4_PUBLIC_READABLE)
     Application($rf : riskFactors[QRiskFactor.QRF1_S4_PUBLIC_READABLE.value], $rf!.factor != "true")
then
    insert(FlagQuestion.QRF_1_ASK_FLAG);
    AskedQuestions $askedQuestions=new AskedQuestions(question:$q1,answer:true);//if i do this way, I get an error defined below
  /* if i follow this approach, it also throws the error.    
 AskedQuestions $askedQuestions=new AskedQuestions();
  $askedQuestions.setQuestion($q1);
          $askedQuestions.setAnswer(false);
          insert($askedQuestions);*/
```

I have to set the values to the defined type variables and then get all the inserted objects in Java and make a JSON from that.
here is the error which I am getting

```
Unable to Analyse Expression drools.insert(FlagQuestion.QRF_1_ASK_FLAG);
    AskedQuestions $askedQuestions=new AskedQuestions(question:$q1,answer:true);
  /*     $askedQuestions.setQuestion($q1);
          $askedQuestions.setAnswer(false);
          insert($askedQuestions);*/;
 [Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: 
 org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper.question()]
 [Near : {... =new AskedQuestions(question:$q1,answer:true); ....}]
```

What I might be doing wrong? I am not finding any reference to this in this repo and the book provided [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-JBoss-Drools-6). Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you re-defining your model in Drools? Why not just import your Java class and use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the book you're referencing, but generally I've been increasingly disappointed with the quality of works from that publisher. Your rules are extremely complicated for reasons I can't fathom given your generally simple use cases.

The declaration of the AskedQuestion type is correct, but the way you're trying to instantiate it on the RHS of your rule is not. Please refer to the [official Drools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-declarations-con_drl-rules).

You are trying to set your 'question' attribute to the `$q1` variable on the left hand side, but `$q1` is some weird 'risk factor' class or something like that. It might be an enum -- you haven't provided any models that your rules are actually using. Per the declaration, the question is supposed to be a String.

```
// do not import your actual Java AskedQuestions class 

declare AskedQuestions
  question : String
  answer : Boolean
end

rule "Example rule"
when
  $q1: QRiskFactor(this == QRiskFactor.QRF1_S4_PUBLIC_READABLE)
  // other conditions here
then
  AskedQuestions askedQuestions = new AskedQuestions();
  askedQuestions.setQuestion( $q1.toString() ); // set question value
  askedQuestions.setAnswer( false ); // set answer value
  // do something with askedQuestions here
end
```

Of course, the easiest solution of all would just be to import your actual AskedQuestions Java model and use that -- it's unclear from your question why you're not just doing that.

```
import com.mycompany.path.to.AskedQuestions;

rule "just using the imported class"
when
  // some conditions
then
  AskedQuestions asked = new AskedQuestions( "questions", true );
  // do stuff with the AskedQuestions instance
end
```

I would recommend relying on the official documentation rather than a book for an old version of Drools, especially when learning. The official docs are extremely well written, and any book is extremely out of date by the time it gets printed.